# .class expected, what do i need to add for it to compile?

Tags: java

I am receiving an error that says '.class' expected in my second class which is the Driver class.

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.Shape;

    /**
     * A Circle is a figure that has a radius, a circumference, 
     * and an area. 
     * @author Kelvynn Cayanan 
     * @version 02/09/2014
    */
    public class Circle
    {

        // Constants
        public static final double pi = 3.1415926; 

        // instance variables
        private double circumference;
        private double area; 
        private double radius;
        private Color color;
        private int xLeft;
        private int yTop;

        /**
        * Positions the circle at the top left.
        */
        public Circle(int x, int y)
        {
            xLeft = 10;
            yTop = 10;
        }

        /**
        * Constructs a circle of radius aRadius
        * @param aRadius is the radius of the circle
        */
        public void draw(double aRadius, Color color)
        {
             radius = aRadius; // assigns value to radius
             circumference = ( 2 * pi * radius); // arithmetic for circumference
             area = ( pi * radius * radius); // arithmetic for area
             color = color; // displays type of color

         }

         public void draw (Graphics2D circle)
         {
         circle.setColor (color);
         }

        /**
        */
        public double getRadius()
        {
            return radius;
        }

        public double getCircumference()
        {
            return circumference;
        }

        public double getArea()
        {
            return area;
        }

        public Color getColor()
        {
            return color;
        }
    }
```

This is my second class where I am having the '.class' expected error. And i believe that it is where I have new Circle(double radius, color)

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;


    /**
    * Main method for circle class.
    * 
    * @author Kelvynn Cayanan 
    * @version 02/09/2014
    */
    public class Driver
    {
         public static void main(String[] args)
        {


            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            double circumference;
            double radius = 5.5;
            double pi = 3.1415926;
            double area = 0;
            Color color;

            Circle circle = new Circle(double radius,color);
            Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double();

    circle.circumerence = 2*radius;
    cirlce.area = pi * (radius * 2);
    circle.x = (double) 10;
    circle.y = (double) 10;
    circle.draw(circle);
    cirlce.setColor(Color.Blue); // setting fill color
    cirlce.fill(circle);
    //Get Radius
    System.out.println("Circle's Radius");
    radius = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("New Circle Object");

    Circle circle = new Circle();

    System.out.println("Area of Circle: " + Circle.getArea());
    System.out.println("Circumference of Circle: " + Circle.getCircumference());

}
```

}

What do i have to add in order for it to compile?

Comment: And where exactly are you getting that error? Which line?

Comment: Please provide exception stack trace

Comment: @Sarz Please read the question, there's no stacktrace, it's a compile-time error.

Answer (score 4):

```
Circle circle = new Circle(double radius,color);
                             ^
                             |
                         syntax error
```

It should be:

```
Circle circle = new Circle(radius, color);
```

Comment: ok so when i remove the 'double', and try to compile, i get another error      required: int, int;  found; double,java.awt.Color; reason: actual argument double cannot be converted to int by method invocation conversion

Answer (score 0):

Take out the 'double' in the argument to create a new Circle object in the Driver class - it is a syntax error.